# android - how fit google map image to screen width

Tags: java, android

I am trying to display an image of google map in my app so it match width of screen.
I used DisplayMetrics as following code and pass it to google to get image in that size (see url parameters). but as you can see in screenshot, it display wrong width. how fix it? I think what I send in parameters for google is not correct?

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int heightP = (int) displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int widthP = (int) displaymetrics.widthPixels;
int height = (int) (displaymetrics.heightPixels / displaymetrics.density);
int width = (int) (displaymetrics.widthPixels / displaymetrics.density);

................

    ImageView imgImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgImage);
    //TextView txtDetail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDetail);

    imgImage.getLayoutParams().width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    imgImage.getLayoutParams().height = (height / 2);
...............

        ImageView gmap = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.googlemap);
        gmap.getLayoutParams().height = 200;
        //gmap.requestLayout();
        String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + estate.getString("maplat") + "," + estate.getString("maplng") + "&zoom=" + estate.getString("mapzoom") + "&size=" + Integer.toString(widthP - 10) + "x200&sensor=false&format=jpeg&&markers=color:red|" + estate.getString("maplat") + "," + estate.getString("maplng");

        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.animated_progress)
                .into(gmap);
```

layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/detailLayer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:padding="8dp"
    tools:context=".DetailActivity">


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textDirection="rtl">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
                style="@style/CKButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:text="@string/txt_manage"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/sold"
                android:visibility="gone" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:textAlignment="gravity" />


 </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

here is image of issue:

[here is issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Yc2V.jpg)

Comment: In layout : set property `android:scaleType="fitXY"` in your imageview.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set property `android:scaleType="fitXY"`  in your imageview.

Answer (score 0):

By using XML , just put the attribute,

```
  android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

to your ImageView. like

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    **android:scaleType="fitXY"**
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />
```

By Java,

```
imageview.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your url parameter is not true because You are sending image width in density pixel which is wrong.

In your url, need to pass only pixel value not dp(density pixel) value.

Please read [this doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#URL_Parameters) for more information about google map url.

It can helps to send which types of parameter pass and get more accurate size of map image.

```
screen_width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;

String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + estate.getString("maplat") + "," + estate.getString("maplng") + "&zoom=" + estate.getString("mapzoom") + "&size=" + Integer.toString(screen_width - 10) + "x200&sensor=false&format=jpeg&&markers=color:red|" + estate.getString("maplat") + "," + estate.getString("maplng");
```

and pass this in your url.